# How to add # Shebang in first line of a file which is an auto create script by another program

Tags: bash, sed, bash-scripting, awk

I am looking for a method to add a shebang `#!/bin/csh -f` to first line of my file , which is actually getting created by a another set of program.

Since this script is auto-created, it should run from bash, when user clicks some button in my tool.

I tried using sed but it didn't work.

```
sed ' 1 s/.*/\#!/bin/csh -f/' filename.
```

and awk

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "%s %s\n", $0, "#!/bin/csh -f"}' filename
```

both of these commands returns following

```
/bin/csh is not an event.
```

Please suggest a better method.

Comment: tried escaping the `!` character in your attempts? as in `\!` instead of plain `!`

Comment: Thanks "Xen2050", i tried your suggestion and this works well.

sed '1 i\#\!\/bin\/csh -f' filename > out.txt

Comment: I'll toss it in an answer then

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `!` character, by using `\!` instead of plain `!`, should give better results. So try:

```
sed '1 i\#\!\/bin\/csh -f' filename > out.txt
```

Comment: If you put `-i` in the `sed` command you can modify the file instead to do the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Awk alternatives

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "#!/bin/csh -f"} {print}' filename > out.sh

awk 'NR==1{print "#!/bin/csh -f"};{print}' filename > out.sh
```

Variant of Xen2050 to modify the file inside instead of redirect it to `out.sh`

```
 sed -i '1 i\#\!\/bin\/csh -f' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nano foo
#!/bin/bash

ctrl-o
enter
ctrl-x
```

This creates a file named foo edits it, type the shabang. save file and exit.

Now everytime you need to insert the shabang to a new file from command line simply cat the file name into the new file, before beginning.

```
touch foo2
cat foo > foo2
```

Alternatively you could use the append operator since and if the file is still empty:

```
cat foo >> foo2.
```

For some reason you cannot simply:

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" > foo2
```

As this will return an error of:

```
bash: !/bin/bash: event not found.
```

If anyone can explain why this does not work and perhaps a way to echo the string into a file this would prevent needing to create a file specifically for this purpose and I would appreciate hearing it.

Comment: Nano is not very good option if you are trying execute it for example from a script. I assume `awk` or `sed` is the correct way to advance here, even though there must be lots of different options.
`!` should be between single quotes, then it'll work. Like so: `echo '#!/bin/bash' > foo2`.